# Rows to Columns in R based on multiple criteria with summary statistics

Tags: r

I have data in this format:

```
ID        Cue       trial     time     accuracy
A         apple     copy      1450     1 
A         dog       copy      2154     1
A         apple     test1     2121     0
A         dog       test2     0        1
A         apple     final     1231     0
A         dog       final     5411     1
```

I need to transform it to look like the following:

```
 ID        Cue       trial     time     accuracy     ID2       Cue2     trial2     time2       accuracy2      ID3       Cue3     trial3     time3       accuracy3
 A         apple     copy      1450     1            A         apple    test1      2121        0              A         apple    final      1231        0
```

**Problem #1:**

I need to append each row of data (from long format) to the end of another row (to wide format) based on matching ID and Cue (e.g., put all the data for Participant A with cue "apple" on a *single row*).

**Problem #2:**

The number of rows is NOT even. Given that I need an even number of columns to make my analyses work, I *only* want to move the items that are "test1" or "test2" if accuracy = 1.

**Problem #3:**

I need to perform summary statistics (count / sum) for the rows I *do not* append to the end of the first row. Basically, I need to know the number of trials that have "test1" or "test2" for each ID & cue combination (in this case, apple only had 1 test1 trial and 1 test2 trial) and put that in a column somewhere.

In short, I need something conceptually like this:

```
A - apple --> row1 -- row2 -- row3 [summary statistics for # rows test1]
A - dog   --> row1 -- row2 -- row3 [summary statistics for # rows test2]
```

I had a formula that I believe was counting the summary statistics

```
dfsummary <- df %>%
   group_by(ID, trial, cue) %>%
   summarise(numRows = length(trial))
```

But I need to line up the rows in how I described first and then append that information in a column to that data frame.

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a sequence column by 'ID' 'Cue' and then `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
out <- dcast(setDT(df1), ID + Cue ~ rowid(ID, Cue), 
      value.var = c("ID", "Cue", "trial", "time", "accuracy"))[,-(1:2)]
```

and then `order` the columns

```
setcolorder(out, order(as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", names(out)))))
```

if needed, change the column names

```
setnames(out, make.unique(sub("[._].*", "", names(out))))
out
#    ID   Cue trial time accuracy ID.1 Cue.1 trial.1 time.1 accuracy.1 ID.2 Cue.2 trial.2 time.2 accuracy.2
#1:  A apple  copy 1450        1    A apple   test1   2121          0    A apple   final   1231          0
#2:  A   dog  copy 2154        1    A   dog   test2      0          1    A   dog   final   5411          1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Cue = c("apple", 
"dog", "apple", "dog", "apple", "dog"), trial = c("copy", "copy", 
"test1", "test2", "final", "final"), time = c(1450L, 2154L, 2121L, 
0L, 1231L, 5411L), accuracy = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Not quite what I want, but I think it could be modified to get there I think.

Instead of have everything on one row, can I have it like this:
A apple --> everything for apple for that ID
A dog --> everything for dog for that ID

Comment: @KalifVaughn  Oops, I was looking at your expected and saw only a single row there

Comment: Thanks so much. Data table seems very powerful and I look forward to learning it further. :)

My next task is to figure out how to compute summary statistics as part of the data table.